# running __init__ inside its own definition

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently learning tkinter from sentdex's tutorial and to me it seems that I'm writing to run `__init__` in its own definition, what does a line like that mean? Is it tKinter's `__init__` function?

```
class seaOfBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
         tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Are you sure this function is in the `tk.Tk` class?

Comment: the class is: class seaOfBTCapp(tk.Tk):

Comment: So it's not being called in its own `__init__` definition, it's calling it from a different class's `__init__` definition.

Comment: This may be an old way to do `super().__init__()`

Comment: ... normally `__init__` is called implicitly and not explicitly... ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner But a subclass needs to call the superclass's `__init__` method explicitly.

Comment: so its the tk.Tk's `__init__` function?

Comment: `tk.Tk` needs to do its own initialization too. In python you have to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's invoking another class's constructor on itself.

This is a fun quirk of python's object-oriented design. "Instance methods" are really just class methods that take the current instance as an implicit parameter. You can, in fact, call them as class methods and provide the object explicitly:

```
ex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# the following are equivalent:
ex.pop(0)         # call the method on the instance, passing it implicitly
list.pop(ex, 0)   # call the method on the class `list`, passing the instance explicitly
```

The same behavior is being invoked here. You're taking the `__init__` method of the `tk.TK` class, and passing `self` in as the "instance". This is an uncommon, but valid, way of accessing methods in the superclass that have been overridden in your subclass (for example, the constructor).

As in @Barmar's answer, a better solution is using `super()`, which produces something resembling an instance of the superclass, which you then call `__init__` on to get the superclass's implementation of `__init__()` passing `self` implicitly, as you would expect.

Comment: wow! this also helped with the whole `self` thing, thanks! =D

Comment: It may be worth noting that `super()` doesn't *actually* return an instance of the parent class, it returns a `super` object that *behaves like* an instance of the parent class, for the purposes of attribute lookup. The difference is minor, it's only things like `type(super())` or `str(super())` that might not work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

What that line does is call your parent class's `__init__` method. That's what would have happened if you didn't define your own method, so if you're not doing anything else in your `__init__`, you should probably just skip it and let the inherited method run normally.

It's also probably better to call `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, rather than naming the parent class explicitly (and needing to pass `self` by hand). This is particularly the case if you might ever use this class in a situation involving multiple inheritance, where explicitly naming the next class to be called can get the MRO wrong. If you're just starting in programming, don't worry too much about this, multiple inheritance is a pretty advanced topic (though it's easier to get right in Python than in many other languages).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is equivalent to the more modern:

```
class seaOfBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
         super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```